# Creating an array of graphs (time evolving) in Java

Tags: java, arraylist, graph, jung, jgrapht

I'm new to Java and working with graphs. I have a time evolving graph (e.g 5 snapshots of the same graph in different instance of time) and I need to compute some basic network metrics like density, size, centrality, etc on each one of them. I was wondering as to what basic data structures I could use to store and perform computation on each graph. I tried using adjacency matrix, but the node size is too large and dynamic which leads to inefficiency. I came across few libraries notably JgraphT to hold undirected graphs

```
    UndirectedGraph<String, DefaultEdge> G =
          new SimpleGraph<String, DefaultEdge>(DefaultEdge.class);
```

But this is for one graph. Is there a way to create an array of these undirected graphs or any other way which I am missing to store time evolving graphs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few options:

(1) You can create an array (or a List, or a Set, etc.) of graphs just as you can of any other object.  If all the timesteps fit easily into memory (say 100 timesteps of 1000 nodes/edges each) then this should work fine.  Here's an example using JUNG:

```
List<Graph<V, E>> graphList = new ArrayList<>(); // Java 7 syntax
Graph<V, E> graph = new DirectedSparseGraph<V, E>();
// populate 'graph'
graphList.add(graph);
```

(2) If the nodes in each graph are all the same (i.e., it's just the edges that are changing), store the nodes once, and store a list of sets of edges, one set for each timestep.

(3) If the whole graph is relatively static, you can store the original graph, and then store deltas (added/removed nodes or edges) for each timestep.  This can be considerably more space-efficient, but requires that you reconstruct steps 1-n in order to see the state at time n+1.

(4) Finally, you can use a single graph, annotate each node/edge with the interval(s) at which it is present, and apply a filter any time you want to apply an algorithm to the graph.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the options. I did consider 2) & 3) but since the graph changes frequently (node-wise), I chose 1). But I was unable to create the array of graphs in JgraphT. Is there any example I could refer to for time evolving graphs (with any other graph library too) ? And option 4) does seem like a good alternative so will give it a try...

Comment: Added a sample using JUNG (I'm not the right person to ask about JGraphT) for how to create a list of graphs; as I said, it's basically the same as creating a list of anything.

Comment: Thank you very much for your time and inputs. :) It has been very helpful and i hope to take it forward from here.!!